# How to use gerrit notedb,I want to query some comment record in db

Tags: gerrit

After I upgrade gerrit version from v2.15 to v3.0,I can not use gsql command to access my db.I know v3.0 use notedb as db,and i also read NoteDB.pdf from website.Does somebody tell me how to access notedb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an easy way to do that because all the data is embedded in the Git repository.

See more info about this [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/homepage/+/md-pages/docs/Notedb.md).

For example, you can see some info about change 56266 if you go to the specific Git repository in the Gerrit server (GERRIT-SITE/git/repo-full-path.git) and execute the following command:

```
git log refs/changes/66/56266/meta
```

Comment: any suggestions to get detail comments?
use git log refs/changes/66/56266/meta,I can see all history with this change.
but i can not see detail of comments.

Comment: It's complicated but if you execute "git rev-list refs/changes/66/56266/meta" you will see all commits related to this change. If you execute "git --no-patch --format="%b" COMMIT" for every commit in this list you'll see more details about reviews and comments.